# proof that such an integral is a measure

Tags: measure-theory

How to prove that this set function is a measure?
$$v(A)= \int_{A} f d\mu $$ and $$f$$ is a non-negative function.

1.The first condition for being a measure is ok because if A is an empty set then $$ v(\emptyset)= \int_{\emptyset} f d\mu = 0 $$
2.From the properties of a measurable and non-negative function we know that $$ \int_{X} fd\mu \geq 0$$ so $$v(A) \geq 0$$
3. I have a problem with the proof for countable additivity, how can this be shown?

Comment: @DavidMitra That won't work here, since $f$ is not necessarily integrable. Since it's non-negative, MCT will work though (as in my solution below)

Answer (score 2):

If $\{A_{i}\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ are disjoint and measurable, let $A = \bigcup_{i} A_{i}$, and define
$$
E_{n} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}
$$
Then $E_{n} \uparrow A$, and thus $f \chi_{E_{n}} \uparrow f$ (since $f$ is non-negative). Monotone Convergence Theorem gives
$$
\nu(A) = \int f \chi_{A} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int f \chi_{E_{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \int f_{\chi_{A_{i}}} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \nu(A_{i})
$$
since $\int f \chi_{A_{i}} = \int_{A_{i}} f = \nu(A_{i})$ by definition.